# .toFixed(1) not working in 8.333333333333334 decimal number

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I'm currently writing the working hour calculation with Time In and Time Out to show working hour with decimal with 1 point. In my case i used .toFixed(1) and any other times are working well but when time in is 09:10 and time out is 17:30 .. It's result show as 8.333333333333334. .toFixed(1) not working in that decimal number. How should i do that.

Here is my code.

```
var time_in = $(elm).closest('tr').find('.time_in').text();
var time_out = $(elm).closest('tr').find('.time_out').text();
var working_time = (new Date("1970-1-1 " + time_out) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + time_in)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 ;
alert(working_time);
var total_work_hour = working_time.toFixed(1) - 1;    //get fixed decimal number and minus 1 for lunch time.
var w_time = $(elm).closest('tr').find('.work_time');
w_time.text(total_work_hour);
```

Comment: `8.333333333333334.toFixed(1)` results in `8.4`. I do not understand the issue. You are also alerting `working_time` and not `working_time.toFixed(1)` so your test is invalid.

Comment: please do a typeof and check if 8.3333333.... is a number.It is working fine in my case.Also note if there is any error in console

Comment: You should not rely on the `Date` constructor being able to reliably parse those date/time strings.

Comment: @Shawn31313 - No, it is 8.3. Not 8.4.

Comment: The result is 8.3, what are you expecting?

Comment: I think OP is getting 7.3000000000001 when subtracting 1 from 8.3, and is mistakenly thinking that's because `.toFixed(1)` is not working. In fact, it's because the math is floating point.

Comment: Why are you rounding _before_ your calculations are done? Round at the end.

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract 1 from the result of `8.333333333333334.toFixed(1)` (which javascript allows you to do even though `Number#toFixed` returns a string), the result is not 7.3 because the machine is using binary floating point arithmetic. For example:

```
0.1 + 0.2 // -> 0.30000000000000004
```

To get around this, do all your arithmetic and *then* call `.toFixed(1)`:

```
var total_work_hour = (working_time - 1).toFixed(1);
```

Comment: It's not just "floating point arithmetic", but "binary floating point arithmetic": `toFixed` takes a number of _decimal_ places.

Comment: Yes, you're right.